# Setting up php-mysql based web application on EC2/linode

Tags: amazon-ec2, web-hosting, vps

I have a new web application which is based on php-mysql.It is a publisher/advertiser platform so I can expect lot of traffic if things go in right direction.

I am considering two solutions to host the site:cloud(ec2) and vps(linode).
EC2 is looking as an expensive vendor compare to linode.
Please guide me how to set up a cloud based web application on ec2 with minimal cost involved.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

This post : http://www.john-nousis.com/development/tutorial-running-a-phpmysql-server-on-ec2-with-ebs/ gives you a step by step tutorial on how to set up a php/MySQL app on EC2.

Info may be a little bit dated though.